# Numerical methods for inverting non positive definite matrices

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm working on a PDE solver and need to invert the following matrix written in block form
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
kM & -S \\
-S & M 
\end{array}\right)
$
where M and S are the usual mass and stiffness matrices, so they are both symmetric and positive definite (k is a time parameter). Obviously it is symmetric but not positive definite so I can't use conjugate gradient or biconjugate gradient methods. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: May I know the underlying PDE?

Comment: Cahn-Hilliard equation.

Answer (score 0):

[Minres](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINRES-Verfahren) is suitable for solving symmetric linear systems iteratively.